# Diff-in-Diff controls useless, when not varying over time?

Tags: inference

I am reading a paper with a Diff-in-Diff approach of the form (where i is the individual and t is the time period):

$y_{it} = a + b_1 * \operatorname{treatment}_i + b_2 * \operatorname{during}_t + b_3 * \operatorname{during}_t * \operatorname{treatment}_i + b_4 \operatorname{control variable}_t + e_{it}$

The control variable varies in different specifications and the coefficient "$b_3$" varies with these control variables which only vary over time.

I am puzzled. I also simulated data and I believe the coefficient $b_3$ should not vary if the control variable does not vary between treatment and control. Am I missing something?